# GPars syntax unfamiliar

Tags: groovy, gpars

I'm coming from a Java background and I'm stuck learning Groovy and Gradle at the same time, since my purpose for one is the other. :-/ I'm also in need of the GPars stuff since speed and parallelism are an issue. Anyway, I see this GPars example and I have some questions which I think are linguistic nuances, rather than library issues, that I don't yet understand.

```
//check whether all elements within a collection meet certain criteria
 GParsPool.withPool(5) { ForkJoinPool pool ->
     assert [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].everyParallel {it > 0}
     assert ![1, 2, 3, 4, 5].everyParallel {it > 1}
 }
```

I see `ForkJoinPool pool ->..`. Why aren't the two lines wrapped in braces like so. Seems like you would loose track of the scope if it were just an optional omission, like for semicolons:

```
//check whether all elements within a collection meet certain criteria
 GParsPool.withPool(5) { ForkJoinPool pool -> {
     assert [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].everyParallel {it > 0}
     assert ![1, 2, 3, 4, 5].everyParallel {it > 1}
   }
 }
```

What is `it`? Is it an iterator? Where did `it` come from?

By what means is it possible to call `.everyParallel` on an Object when it's never been explicitly wrapped by something that has that function as far as I can tell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll start with the disclaimer that I am by no means a GPars expert, but I have used it in a couple of situations, so hopefully there can be something helpful here (updates from the community are welcome).

**[Closures](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_closures)**

Groovy Closures are blocks of code that can be passed around. When a parameter is passed into the block, it will come in before the `->` notation. For example:

```
GParsPool.withPool(5) { ForkJoinPool pool ->
  // Here the `pool` object is available to use for processing.
}
```

In the case that you do not provide a defined variable, there is an implicit `it` object included. The above closure could be written in the following ways:

```
GParsPool.withPool(5) { Object it ->
  // Generically stating that a single object will be passed in, called "it". In this example it is a `ForkJoinPool` object.
}

GParsPool.withPool(5) {
  // No "it" object is specified, but you can still use "it" because it is implied.
}
```

**everyParallel()**

> The GParsPool class enables a ParallelArray-based (from JSR-166y)
>   concurrency DSL for collections and objects. [Source](http://www.gpars.org/guide/guide/dataParallelism.html#dataParallelism_parallelCollections)

If I understand this correctly, there is functionality automatically added when using `GParsPool.withPool()`, which allows you to use methods like `everyParallel()`. Dynamic programming FTW! I'm guessing it uses the Groovy `metaClass` capability to add methods dynamically at runtime, so that you can call them without adding them yourself.